# How to bring data into a bean without direct relation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am facing an issue, 
I have a table name

```
1. AddressTbl
2. CompanyTbl
3. PersonTbl
```

AddressTbl contains two columns

```
1. isCompany
2. relatedId
```

in this case,

```
If(isCompany == true){
    fetch record from companyTbl by "relatedId"
}else{
    fetch record from person byTbl "relatedId"
}
```

so the issue is, I want to crate a new ""Transient"" field which contains then name, it may be company, or it may be person, according to above condition.
How can I do that

Some how I found a solution, we can write a query in @Formula annotation, like

```
@Formula("(select min(p.manufactured_date) from Product p where p.product_id = product_id)") private Date oldProductDate;
```

reference 
http://www.javamakeuse.com/2015/08/tutorial-hibernate-formula-annotation.html

but it's not working, can anyone help me to solve this thing.

Comment: Try something like this `@Formula(value = "case when isCompany='true' then companyName else personName ")`

Comment: companyName is into companyTbl

Comment: and personName  is into PersonTbl

Comment: DevSabby, it is the example of a query, `companyName` and `personName` are fetched records, and you can use anything instead of it.